# Ошибка с inline

Tags: c++

Подскажите, пожалуйста, с чем может быть связана эта ошибка линковки:

```
1>Source.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: char const * __thiscall my::string::c_str(void)const " (?c_str@string@my@@QBEPBDXZ) referenced in function _main  
1>Source.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: unsigned int __thiscall my::string::length(void)const " (?length@string@my@@QBEIXZ) referenced in function _main
```

Сам код:

```
// string.h
#pragma once
#include <cstddef>
#include <cassert>
#include <cstring>

namespace my {
    class string
    {
    private:
        char *m_Str;
        std::size_t m_Size;         
        std::size_t m_Capacity;
    public:
        string();

        // copy ctor
        string(const string& str);

        string(const char *str);

        inline const char *c_str() const noexcept;
        inline std::size_t length() const noexcept;
    };
}
```

```
// string.c
#include "string.h"

namespace my {
    string::string()
        : m_Str(nullptr), m_Size(0), m_Capacity(0)
    {
    }

    string::string(const string & str)
    {
        m_Size = str.m_Size;
        m_Capacity = str.m_Capacity;

        if (m_Capacity == 0)
        {
            m_Str = nullptr;
        }
        else
        {
            m_Str = new char[m_Capacity];
            assert(m_Str != nullptr);

            memcpy(m_Str, &str, m_Capacity);
        }
    }

    string::string(const char * str)
    {
        if (str)
        {
            m_Size = m_Capacity = strlen(str) + 1;
            m_Str = new char[m_Capacity];
            assert(m_Str != nullptr);
            std::strcpy(m_Str, str);
        }
        assert(str != nullptr);
    }

    inline const char * string::c_str() const noexcept
    {
        return m_Str;
    }

    inline std::size_t string::length() const noexcept
    {
        return m_Size ? m_Size - 1 : m_Size;
    }
}
```

```
// Source.c
#include <iostream>
#include "string.h"
using namespace my;

int main()
{
    const char *c = "Hello world";
    string a = c;
    const char *b = a.c_str();
    int size = a.length();
}
```

Если убрать`inline`, то все будет работать, а с `inline` ругается линковщик. В чем тут проблема?

Comment: для `inline` функции определение должно быть доступно при подключении заголовочного файла, а не валяться в какой-то другой единице трансляции. А чего вы вообще хотите добиться используя `inline` тут?

Comment: @VTT чтобы при вызове метода, например `length()`, его результат просто подставлялся.

Comment: Для этого надо использовать LTO и /Ob2.

Comment: @VTT а можно, пожалуйста, подробнее или ссылку, где можно почитать?

Comment: @ARHovsepyan методы по умолчании вроде встроенные, но, если это явно указать, это плохо?

Comment: В документации к параметрам vc++ @ARHovsepyan Методы являются неявно inline только когда определение дано прямо в классе.

Comment: @elvy: Ключевое слово `inline` уже давно не имеет никакого отношения к "подставлению результатов методов".

Comment: @VTT определение валялось в той же единице трансляции, но я уже понял, что должно было валятся в заголовочном файле.

Comment: Если ба оно было в той же, то ошибки бы не было. а тут вызов из Source.c, а определение в string.c (почему кстати .c?)

Comment: @VTT да, ошибся. В моем случае получается, что в единице трансляции `Source.c` (там на самом деле `.cpp`) нету определения `inline` функций.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

У вас какое шиворот-навыворот наблюдается.

Основное назначение ключевого слова `inline` в языке С++ - дать вам возможность помещать определения сущностей (функций и переменных) напрямую в заголовочные файлы, т.е. в файлы, которые будут много раз включаться в тексте программы. Использование ключевого слова `inline` предотвратит ошибки компиляции (множественного определения), которые в таком случае возникли бы без `inline`.

Все.

Вы использовали в своем коде ключевое слово `inline` с методами класса, но определение этих методов в заголовочный файл не поместили. Зачем же вы тогда вообще использовали ключевое слово `inline`???

---

Если вы объявили некую сущность как `inline`, то определение этой сущности должно быть видно везде, где эта сущность используется. У вас же из `Source.cpp` ничего не видно.

Comment: то есть `inline` имеет смысл определения метода в заголовочном файле? Но я ведь могу его и без `inline` там определить. В чем разница тогда?

Comment: @elvy: Как именно "там определить"? Если вы поместите определение метода прямо *внутрь* класса, то тогда `inline` не нужно - оно и так подразумевается. Если вы поместите определение метода *рядом* с классом, то тогда `inline` *нужно*. Иначе (без `inline`) вы получите ошибки множественного определения.

Comment: если определить метод вне класса, но в том же заголовочном файле, тогда нужно помечать как `inline`. То есть больше никакого смысла это слово не несет?

Comment: Извиняюсь за оффтоп, но разве это ключевое слово не используется как рекомендация компилятору подставить тело метода в точку вызова? Или расположение метода в заголовочном файле имеет такой же эффект?

Comment: @elvy Для функций - не несет. Не забываем только, что `inline` также используется для определения переменных в заголовочном файле и для определения inline-пространств имен. То есть ваше "больше никакого смысла не несет" - это слишком жестко сказано.

Comment: @aa_talanin Современные реализации рассматривают на предмет подставления абсолютно все вызовы, определения функций которых они могут видеть из точки вызова. Решение о подставлении они принимают на основе своих внутренних критериев, которые не учитывают (могут не учитывать) никакие "рекомендации". Так что роль ключевого слова `inline` свелась только к тому, чтобы дать компилятору возможность *видеть* полное определение функции. А принимать решение он будет сам и на вашу расстановку слов `inline` он внимания обращать не будет.

Comment: @AnT Я просто думал, что `inline` это как рекомендация компилятору, мол вставь это вместо функции. Теперь буду знать, спасибо. Пойду еще почитаю на эту тему. Если у вас есть какие-нибудь статьи на примете, то можете посоветовать.